# PostgreSQL database privilege confusion

Tags: postgresql

What does it mean if `\l` shows no database privileges for any user whatsoever on a certain database, but, `has_database_privilege()` confirms ALL privileges are present for a certain role (which is validated by the fact that the role can indeed connect to the database). Is this even a possible situation?
Happening on version 10.15.

Comment: Please post your shell/terminal session. Where you specifying `/l`? What login are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `\l` shows absolutely no privileges information for a database, it means that the database has default privileges.  The default is for PUBLIC to have CONNECT and TEMP (but not CREATE).

has_database_privilege will count privileges of PUBLIC as being possessed by any named user, so it may show 'true' even though `\l` doesn't explicitly list them.